# Cannot delete a sub-sub....-sub folder while trying to delete a git repository in a git repository

Tags: linux, git, rm, rmdir

I wanted to delete a git repository and while doing that it gives me

```
Error when getting information for file “/leg/home/chaitanya/MyFolder/React/portfolio/node_modules/.cache/gh-pages/https!github.com!cvsschaitanya!portfolio.git/.git/HEAD”: Bad message
```

Then I went for the big guns and tried `rm -rf` and it gives

```
rm: cannot remove '.git/HEAD': Bad message
```

There is nothing else in the folder except this one seemingly empty folder which doesn't want to go.

What can I do?

Comment: This is the sure sign of a corrupted filesystem. Likely you're using some userland filesystem (like encrypted home folder, or sshfs) and there's something wrong with the underlying fs. You can usually use repair tools to fix it. (PS sometimes a reboot/remount is enough)

Comment: I am using a file system from another ubuntu partition, which I cannot boot into anymore. What kind of tools should I try?

Comment: Well that sounds like it was a bad idea from the start.  "My OS won't boot, and I don't know why.  I guess I'll just work around it to try to keep using that disk."  Really? Much better would have been (1) make a backup of everything you don't want to lose and (2) boot a separate rescue disk to diagnose and maybe fix the system disk.  Continuing to use a disk that you have reason to suspect is going bad is asking for data corruption and loss.

Comment: Your best option at this point is probably to do what you should have done in the first place (backup data, diagnose the disk problem, proceed appropriately from there).  "Proceed appropriately from there" probably means at least reformatting the partition on which the corrupt file system resides, but it may well mean decommissioning that whole disk.

Comment: I suppose gparted should have it, but a google should yeild a lot more useful information